# What does 'on earth' mean?

Tags: idioms, exclamatives

I have a query about the meaning of 'on earth'.
Here is an example.

> What on earth are you doing under the table?

At here, what is the purpose of 'on earth'?

Answer (score 3):

It's an expression, similar to *what the hell*.

It expresses the speaker's disbelief or amazement towards what the hearer is doing. Normally this expression is used for things that someone is doing that are considered to be either really weird or really bad.

Comment: Thanks then How much different between 'what the hell' and 'on earth'?  I am familliar with what the hell rather on earth. Actually this is the first time what I heard it

Comment: "What the hell" seems a lot more infornal and perhaps even rude. "What on earth" is less informal.

Comment: @gmotree "what on earth" is what somebody more cultured would say in a formal setting. "What the hell" is what you would say to a buddy in an informal setting.

Comment: It's really a case of 'pick a word'. "What the…" can actually stand alone, as the audience will anticipate their own word. "What on earth" is possibly the most polite form, useable to any audience. From there they decline rapidly.

Comment: Apart from _what the ..._ and _what on ..._, there is also the _what in ..._ option, as in "What in ...'s name are you doing?", where the ... can be a deity of your choice, or other options like _heaven_.

Comment: "What on Earth..." signifies total ignorance and lack of prior knowledge. "What the hell..." tends more to signify shock, surprise and disdain.

Comment: Moves quickly down to WTF?!?

Answer (score 0):

What on earth

This expression is used to add emphasis to questions. In other words, you use the expression when you are extremely surprised, angry, or confused about something. The phrase is used in informal English.

You can use "what the hell" instead, which is also informal, but it's impolite.